# using calloc on an array of struct, in a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct, calloc

This is my struc

```
//global
typedef struct {
    char idCode[MATLENGTH + 10];
    char *name;
} stud;
```

In main, I do this

```
Int main() {

    stud *students;
    createStudentArray(students);
    ....
```

What I'm trying to do, is:

-pass the array (*student) to a function

-make the function alloc. the array

This is the function i wrote

```
createStudentArray(stud *students) {

    //I get this value from a file
    int nstud = 3;
    students calloc(nstud, sizeof(students));
    return;
}
```

the problem is:

-when I try to assign any value to a students field, it doesn't work

ex.

```
Int main() {

    stud *students;
    createStudentArray(students);
    ....
    strcpy(students[0].name, "Nicola"); //this is where i get the error
```

My guess is that, in some way, I'm not allocating the array correctly, because, when i try to do

```
strcpy(students[0].name, "Nicola");
```

in the createStudentArray function, it wortks just fine. So it looks like I am passing the array by value, and not by reference.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In C, it is `int main`, not `void main`. C is not Java :-)

Comment: @Jens - C supports multiple variants too.

Comment: @HenkHolterman No, not for `main`'s return type (this is not about a freestanding implementation). You didn't write the code to call main, someone else did expecting it to return `int`, so you are not free to declare it with an arbitrary return type.

Comment: Officially it should indeed be `int main()` , `void main()` is allowed as an 'implementation defined' feature. Lots of Q+A about it on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `students` pointer is passed by value. Any assignment to it inside `createStudentArray` remains invisible to the caller.

You have two options to fix this:

- Return the newly allocated pointer and assign it in the caller, or
- Accept a pointer-to-pointer, and assign with an indirection operator.

Here is the first solution:

```
stud *createStudentArray() {
    //I get this value from a file
    int nstud = 3;
    stud *students = calloc(nstud, sizeof(students));
    ...
    return students;
}
...
stud *students = createStudentArray();
```

Here is the second solution:

```
void createStudentArray(stud ** pstudents) {
    //I get this value from a file
    int nstud = 3;
    *pstudents = calloc(nstud, sizeof(students));
    ...
}
...
stud *students;
createStudentArray(&students); // Don't forget &
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, arguments are passed by values, not by reference.

Changes made to arguments in callee function won't affect variables in caller function.

To modify caller's variables from callee function, use pointers.

```
createStudentArray(stud **students) {

    //I get this value from a file
    int nstud = 3;
    *students = calloc(nstud, sizeof(stud)); // this should be sizeof(stud), not students
    return;
}

int main() {

    stud *students;
    createStudentArray(&students);
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your function only the local pointer will be assigned the new address to the chunk of your allocated memory.
To get it from outside you need to use a pointer to a pointer like so:

```
createStudentArray(stud **students) { ... }
```

and call it like this:

```
createStudentArray(&students);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are correct, students is passed as value to CreateStudentsArray(), either you change it to accept a **stud or you make it return a pointer to the created array.

My suggestion is to use a pointer to a pointer and use the * operator to dereference it.

```
createStudentArray(stud **students) {

    //I get this value from a file
    int nstud = 3;
    *students = calloc(nstud, sizeof(students));
    return;
}

    void main(){
    stud = *students;
    ...
    createStudentsArray(&students);
    ...
    strcpy....
```